# ng-file-upload is accepting any file type when ngf-accept="'image/*'"

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

been uploading text files using this button, the check on the file type isn't working for me, the file is considered valid.

```
    <button ng-hide="uploading" class="btn centered" type="file"
ngf-select="uploadFiles($file, $invalidFiles)" accept="'image/*'"
ngf-max-size="4MB" ngf-accept="'image/*'">
  {{(boardingData.profile_pic_url) ? "Change Photo" : "Upload a Photo"}}
</button>
```

Comment: Try changing button to input

Comment: @Love-Kesh I really want to keep it a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use `ng-file-upload` fairly heavily in our app, but we do not use the `ngf-accept` directive.  However, you don't need to use this to be able to filter the file type being passed in.  Assuming you had the following `<div>` for dragging:

```
<div ngf-drop="" ng-model="files" class="some_class_here" ngf-allow-dir="false">
```

Then there would be a scoped variable in your controller called `$scope.files`.  You can simply check the `type` attribute of `$scope.files` to see what the file type is.  If you wanted to check for files beginning with `image/`, then you could use this:

```
if ($scope.files.startsWith("image/")) {
    console.log("You dragged an image file");
    // or whatever your logic is
}
```

You can handle the file type appropriately from your controller with this information.  Note that not all files show up as having a type, which is something to also keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but I still use this tool myself and was trying to figure out why I couldn't leave out `accept` if I had `ngf-accept` specified without errors. Turns out `ngf-accept` requires ticks and `accept` doesn't.

Only use the ' ticks in the ngf attributes e.g. `ngf-accept="'image/*'"` or `ngf-pattern`, e.g. `ngf-pattern="'image/*'"` or `ngf-pattern="'.jpg,.png'"`.

In `accept`, you should use `accept="image/*"`.